# Map user role to LDAP group

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have been looking for a while online and can't find how do I map a role to user group in JBoss.

I will be maintaining user groups in LDAP but the roles will be local, so I want to have a way of mapping the role to LDAP group in a static way - in property file or in xml config.